# How can I add default postfix value while inserting or updating into my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, sql-insert

I have table Tbl

```
ID | Name    | Email
-------------------------
1  | Sample1 | NULL
2  | Sample2 | NULL
3  | Sample3 | NULL
```

I want to update "Email" field such a way that it will be having some fixed postfix value to it, so that after updating my table data in table will look like below

```
ID | Name    | Email
-------------------------
1  | Sample1 | Sample1@abc.com
2  | Sample2 | Sample2@abc.com
3  | Sample3 | Sample3@abc.com
```

So is there any default setting or option available in to have any fixed postfix values to each value updated or inserted while creating or designing table?

So that I only need to write below statement

```
UPDATE Tbl SET Email = Name
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO Tbl (ID, Name, Email)
VALUES (4, 'Sample4', 'Sample4')
```

And it will do rest of work by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is always the same (which seems unlikely), you could use a computed column instead:

```
alter table tbl add email as (Name + '@abc.com');
```

The value is then computed when it is used.

Comment: I have edited the original question, please help me in this.

Comment: It worked for me as my requirement was to add new column into an existing table. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should works :
`Update Tbl Set Email = Name + '@abc.com'`

[EDIT]
To write your `insert` as you want to, you have to use a `Trigger`

`Create Trigger on Tbl after insert ...`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189799(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Since you edited your question, I invite you to recreate your Email column as @Gordon Linoff suggested.

Comment: I have edited original question, please help me in this.

Comment: Right @Gordon Linoff suggestion worked for me. Thanks.